# How to include German characters in mailto href in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, localization, outlook, mailto

I want a simple mailto tag that supports special (German) characters in email body:

> Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü ß

I wrote my code in the following fashion:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <a href="mailto:test@test.com?subject=test&body=START%20%C3%84%20%C3%A4%20%C3%96%20%C3%B6%20%C3%9C%20%C3%BC%20%C3%9F%20END">Email link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

On my machine Outlook generated an email with body as:

> START Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü ß END

At my German client's end the email body generated is:

> START Ã„ Ã¤ Ã– Ã¶ Ãœ Ã¼ ÃŸ END

Where does the problem lie?

Comment: Are you sending your email as UTF8? I don't think you can specify that in the URL, but you can in Outlook/other mail client

Comment: It that any configuration change in outlook ??

Answer (score 1):

Robert was Right, there is an option called : Enable UTF-8 support for mailto:protocol
in Outlook @

Tools > Options > Mail Format > International Options > [x] Enable UTF-8 support for mailto:protocol

I enabled that option and it worked in the client's machine,

Although I wouldn't expect ppl to change their machine's outlook config to support my web app, but it seems that this is the only way possible right now, I am open to more suggestions though

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution.

Try setting up Thunderbird as your default `mailto:` handler and open the link. Then set up Outlook and open it again.

Thunderbird will display the body correctly while Outlook goes berserk...

Comment: Robert was Right, there is an option called :  Enable UTF-8 support for mailto:protocol in Outlook @ Tools > Options > Mail Format > International Options > [x] Enable UTF-8 support for mailto:protocol

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the down-vote. Good look finding these settings in Outlook Express.

Comment: I am happy you took it constructively